# Issue with google chrome using anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I am styling anchor tag using CSS and I am not getting expected result when I am checking it on Google Chrome.

```
<a class="main-anchor" href="#">Anchor</a>
```

I am using following CSS code:

```
.main-anchor:link{
  color:black;
}
```

When I am checking it on Chrome it is not changing color to black.

But using `.main-anchor:visited{ color:black;}` it is changing the color.

Why it is so?

Comment: There could be a couple things, but try styling the selector without the `:link`. If that doesn't work, you may want to look to see if you have another `a` selector overriding it. Or do you mean the `hover` state?

Answer (score 1):

> Styles defined by the `:link` and `:visited` pseudo-classes can be overridden by any subsequent user-action pseudo-classes (`:hover` or `:active`) that have at least equal specificity. To style links appropriately, put the :link rule before all other link-related rules, as defined by the **LVHA-order:** :link — :visited — :hover — :active. The :visited pseudo-class and :link pseudo-class are mutually exclusive. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link)

LVHA can be remembered easily as LoVe HAte.

In your example, you likely clicked that link so that `:visited` kicked in and overrode `:link`.

If none was declared, typically default link is blue, visited is purple.

Comment: Correct stickers, but the user mentions that they are using chrome, so i think she means they are working on other browsers but not on chrome

Comment: That means I must have clicked that link that's why a:link is not working. But I have one question: even if it is visited reloading the page should make it again not visited? It might be a silly question to you but I am just starting web dev.

Comment: I believe it was not only Chrome but all browsers basically  @AdamBasha

Comment: It doesn't reload it @xyz because it is saved in the browser history. If you clear the browser history, then it will work.\

Comment: @Stickers Thank's it clear my doubt. That mean I might have clicked the link that's why a:link is not working. So I think it is not google chrome issue. I am just starting that's why I got confused.

Comment: Yes @AdamBasha even an anchor `#` link will be saved in history, something like mypage/ vs mypage/#